# JSONobject inside JSONObject in java

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I have following request mapping:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/reCalculated", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody void reCalculated(JSONObject obj) {

    obj.
}
```

and then i have incoming json

```
{"params":{"date_a":"2017-05-01","date_b":"2017-05-02"}}
```

but in java, `obj.` only gives me options `toString()` and `toJSONString()`
meanwhile all the tutorials, and few threads clearly tell me i should be able to do `obj.getJSONObject("params")` Why is this? how can i access my parameters?

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
 </dependency>
```

is the dependency.

Comment: Why are you not considering defining a POJO data model and map the @RequestBody to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json-simple` library had method `get(String name)` and need external type casting like below

```
String name = (String) jsonObject.get("name");
JSONArray msg = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("messages");
long age = (Long) jsonObject.get("age");
```

But `gson` library has predefined methods [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson)

```
public JsonObject getAsJsonObject(String memberName)
public JsonArray getAsJsonArray(String memberName)
```

**Maven dependency**

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
<dependency>
<groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
<artifactId>gson</artifactId>
<version>2.8.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get JSONString from your param

```
Gson gson = (new GsonBuilder()).create();
jsonString = obj.get("params").getAsString();
JsonObject param= gson.fromJson(jsonString, JsonObject.class);
```

As `Deadpool` said, you want to use `gson` but you added `json-simple` dependency.